# Find earliest non-NULL datetime from several datetime columns in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table in my database (SQL Server 2012) which holds multiple datetime fields. Assume all of the fields are nullable. I am trying to find the earliest non-NULL date that exists for each row.

My attempted solution has been to use a *horrible* looking CASE expression:

```
--To return the earliest non-NULL time that exists from table tmp
--Datetime fields are dt_lab_instrument, dt_lab_scan, dt_arrived, dt_receipted

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN tmp.dt_lab_instrument IS NOT NULL AND tmp.dt_lab_instrument <= tmp.dt_lab_scan AND tmp.dt_lab_instrument <= tmp.dt_arrived AND tmp.dt_lab_instrument <= tmp.dt_receipted THEN tmp.dt_lab_instrument
        WHEN tmp.dt_lab_scan IS NOT NULL AND tmp.dt_lab_scan <= tmp.dt_lab_instrument AND tmp.dt_lab_scan <= tmp.dt_arrived AND tmp.dt_lab_scan <= tmp.dt_receipted THEN tmp.dt_lab_scan
        WHEN tmp.dt_arrived IS NOT NULL AND tmp.dt_arrived <= tmp.dt_lab_instrument AND tmp.dt_arrived <= tmp.dt_lab_scan AND tmp.dt_arrived <= tmp.dt_receipted THEN tmp.dt_arrived
        WHEN tmp.dt_receipted IS NOT NULL AND tmp.dt_receipted <= tmp.dt_lab_instrument AND tmp.dt_receipted <= tmp.dt_lab_scan AND tmp.dt_receipted <= tmp.dt_arrived THEN tmp.dt_receipted
        ELSE '1990-01-01' --If all else fails return dummy date value
    END
from tmp
```

This is ugly, inefficient, does not handle nulls, difficult to scale (i.e. just try add a couple more date fields to the mix!) and just seems wrong. But I seem to have a mental block on how to better address this.

I know I can handle nulls by using the ISNULL function to replace any NULL datetime values with dates in the distant future, but that seems to be just making ugly code even uglier.

Please can someone help me address this in a better and more effective manner? MANY thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `VALUES()` operator to un-pivot the date columns into rows and `MIN()` to find the earliest

```
select *
from   tmp t
       cross apply
       (
           select min(dt) as min_dt
           from
           (
               values (dt_lab_instrument), (dt_lab_scan), (dt_arrived), (dt_receipted)
           ) m (dt)
       ) m
```

to handle `If all else fails return dummy date value`, you can use

`ISNULL(min(dt), '1990-01-01')`

or

`COALESCE(min(dt), '1990-01-01')`

Comment: Outstanding - I have just tested and this does exactly what I needed. Many thanks Squirrel

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right you want to get the earliest of this 4 fields

```
dt_lab_instrument
dt_lab_scan
dt_arrived
dt_receipted
```

So, you can use MIN() function for select all min values from this fields, then select min value from this fields

```
SELECT MIN(C)
    FROM (VALUES 
    (SELECT MIN(dt_lab_instrument) from tmp where dt_lab_instrument is not null),
    (SELECT MIN(dt_lab_scan) from tmp where dt_lab_instrument is not null),
    (SELECT MIN(dt_arrived) from tmp where dt_lab_instrument is not null),
    (SELECT MIN(dt_receipted) from tmp where dt_lab_instrument is not null) 
    AS v (C)
```

Comment: Thanks - does this give the earliest for each row or just earliest value across the whole table?

Comment: give it the earliest value across the whole table, to get the earliest of each row you need to create a counter, put this code in a loop and filter (is not null and id = @counter)